# Is it possible in WCF REST 4 to return HTML as one of the response formats

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I have a service which I am writing that is intended to be used by multiple callers, including  ones that are incapable of receiving or parsing XML or JSON.

I know its possible to return HTML from a service response using the raw stream, but what I would like to be able to do is to return one of either XML, JSON, or HTML depending on the Accepts-Type header passed by the client.

I could do it with seperate URLs but this is replacing a system which already has a well defined API layer.

Are there any examples of doing this available, or does anyone know what parts of the pipeline would need to be extended?

(Addendum): I already know about AutomaticFormatSelection and have it enabled, but I would like to support all three (or more) formats (HTML, JSON, XML, etc) from a single endpoint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But you'll need to create a new *message formatter* which knows how to convert between a CLR type (the operation response) and the HTML page. The simplest way to do that is to wrap the original formatter in a new formatter, so when you get a response for requests with `Accept: text/html` you use your logic, but for other requests you use the original formatter.

The formatter doesn't have a way to get access to the incoming requests, though, so we can use a message inspector to provide that as well.

The code below shows one possible implementation of such formatter / inspector pair.

```
public class StackOverflow_10519075
{
    [DataContract(Name = "Person", Namespace = "")]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [WebGet]
        Person GetPerson();
    }
    public class Service : ITest
    {
        public Person GetPerson()
        {
            return new Person { Name = "John Doe", Age = 33 };
        }
    }
    public class MyHtmlAwareFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
    {
        IDispatchMessageFormatter original;
        public MyHtmlAwareFormatter(IDispatchMessageFormatter original)
        {
            this.original = original;
        }

        public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
        {
            this.original.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
        }

        public Message SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters, object result)
        {
            MyUseHtmlExtension useHtml = OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find<MyUseHtmlExtension>();
            if (useHtml != null && useHtml.UseHtmlResponse)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("<html><head><title>Result of " + useHtml.OperationName + "</title></head>");
                sb.AppendLine("<body><h1>Result of " + useHtml.OperationName + "</h1>");
                sb.AppendLine("<p><b>" + result.GetType().FullName + "</b></p>");
                sb.AppendLine("<ul>");
                foreach (var prop in result.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    string line = string.Format("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(result, null));
                    sb.AppendLine("<li>" + line + "</li>");
                }
                sb.AppendLine("</ul></body></html>");
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
                Message reply = Message.CreateMessage(messageVersion, null, new RawBodyWriter(bytes));
                reply.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Raw));
                HttpResponseMessageProperty httpResp = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                reply.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, httpResp);
                httpResp.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "text/html";
                return reply;
            }
            else
            {
                return original.SerializeReply(messageVersion, parameters, result);
            }
        }

        class RawBodyWriter : BodyWriter
        {
            private byte[] bytes;

            public RawBodyWriter(byte[] bytes)
                : base(true)
            {
                this.bytes = bytes;
            }

            protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Binary");
                writer.WriteBase64(this.bytes, 0, this.bytes.Length);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
    }
    public class MyHtmlAwareInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name];
            string accept = httpRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept];
            string operationName = request.Properties[WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector.HttpOperationNamePropertyName] as string;
            if (accept == "text/html")
            {
                OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Add(new MyUseHtmlExtension { UseHtmlResponse = true, OperationName = operationName });
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }
    }
    class MyUseHtmlExtension : IExtension<OperationContext>
    {
        public void Attach(OperationContext owner) { }
        public void Detach(OperationContext owner) { }
        public bool UseHtmlResponse { get; set; }
        public string OperationName { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyHtmlAwareEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyHtmlAwareInspector());
            foreach (DispatchOperation operation in endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
            {
                operation.Formatter = new MyHtmlAwareFormatter(operation.Formatter);
            }
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true });
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyHtmlAwareEndpointBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        WebClient c;

        c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/GetPerson"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/xml";
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/GetPerson"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        c = new WebClient();
        c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html";
        Console.WriteLine(c.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/GetPerson"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow awesome @carlosfigueira, thank you. I will take a look and implement this.